# Unable to get rid of -Wfree-nonheap-object warnings

Tags: c, gcc, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to migrate code from older `gcc` (`7.5.0`)
to newer `11.3.0`. All working, tested code, but I am not able to get rid of some warnings (I use `-Werror`) like:

```
warning: ‘free’ called on pointer ‘ptr357’ with nonzero offset 24 [`-Wfree-nonheap-object`]
```

Even with `-Wno-free-nonheap-object` ! I searched some articles and also tried to disable
Link-time-optimization with `-fno-lto`, still I see a lot of the above, and bunch of the following

```
warning: type of ‘do_enable_p’ does not match original declaration [-Wlto-type-mismatch]
```

(even with `-Wno-lto-type-mismatch`)

Am I missing some other
flags to `gcc` or this has to be gotten rid of, with the `#pragmas` in code ?

P.S. I am on Ubuntu-22.04

Comment: With each new version of GCC, the compiler gets better at detecting problems. Perhaps this is a bug in your code that has flown under the radar? Just because code has been running and seemingly working for several years doesn't mean it's bug-free, What is the code doing? Is it possible to create a [mre]?

Comment: I have my code, and quite many third-party libraries! I cannot fix all of them! :( I can try to come up with a minimal example, but I want to see if I can silence these with the right set of flags and move forward with the compilation, first.

Comment: The first instinct when getting a warning from the compiler, should be to examine the code, to make sure it doesn't actually have a bug. Not to silence the warning. While it can happen that there are false positives, more often than not the compiler is right, and there is a problem in your code.

Comment: Using `-Werror` and disabling a bunch of warnings seems counterproductive.

Comment: `Even with -Wno-free-nonheap-object` If that is true, then this looks like a compiler bug. You have to create a sample source code that reproduces the problem. I cannot reproduce - using `-Wno-free-nonheap-object` disables the warning. Are you _sure_ you passed correct options? `(I use -Werror)` If so, why is the message a warning?

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: If you just want to move forward with the compilation, why not remove `-Werror` for now?